# Why does RSS include ignored questions?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, feed, ignored-tags

Can I hide ALL questions which has tag included in my ignored list?

I have about 35 ignored tags and I would like to hide it all from RSS feed

Comment: It's not your personal RSS feed, so it has no idea what tags you have ignored.

Comment: and it can't be modificated ? It's just PHP script (or whatever SO use) generating that feed, am I right?

Comment: Do you expect SO to create a custom RSS feed for each user?

Comment: isn't RSS content ALMOST exactly same as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ "Top Questions"?

Comment: @Genesis - if it's super easy, go ahead and code something for yourself that dynamically fetches your ignored tags from SO, checks each question in the feed and removes it if it matches one of those tags.  It's just PHP and SQL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This filter, which shows content from all sites with tags you find interesting](https://stackexchange.com/filters/886/interesting-tags) might be what you are looking for. If not, play around with the filters and create a feed you like better.